# Call an ajax function by clicking on link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, hyperlink, drupal-7

i have implemented a simple ajax call where i update some database fields by getting the inputs from the user.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>?q=newPage/updatetheItems",
    data:{
            id:id,
            item1 : item1,
            item2:item2, 
            item3:item3
        },
    error: function(returnval) {
                alert("Failure"+id);
        },
    success: function (returnval) {
                alert("suces");
                $('#' + id + ' #item1_id').html(contentitem1.trim());
                $('#' + id + ' #item2_id').html(contentitem2.trim());
                $('#' + id + ' #item3_id').html(contentitem3.trim());
        });

});
```

Now i would like to get the confirmation from the authenticated user. So, i want to execute this function, when user clicks a link which is mailed to his email-id.
i want to make clear of these things:

1- where shall i store these variables till he clicks the link.

2- how shall the function written in the "newPage/updatetheItems" shall be executed. the function written under this page is ( Drupal )

```
$items['newPage/updatetheItems'] = array( 
   'title' => 'Update items', //page title
   'description' => 'Update items',
   'page callback' => 'newitems_updatestransfer',
   'page arguments' => array('access content'),
   'access callback' => TRUE
 );
```

Please give me guidance on this.
i think by using Get/Post  we can save the data in the link itself, but then shall i be able to call the Ajax through it. Please help.

Comment: is the confirmation on another page..??

Comment: yes...its in the page where i calls newitems_updatestransfer()

Comment: need some help... @Outlooker can u look on it..

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be 2 possible ways

1.Using `session` variable you could store the data.A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages. Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer.

2.Using `variable_set` and `variable_get` you could save your data  in drupal

**FYI**

[variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7)

[variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)